# Get the invoice number associated with a registration

Tags: laravel

I want to get the invoice number associated with a registration id. So I have this code:

```
  $user = Auth::user();

  $registration = $user->registrations()->
  with(["invoice"])->where("id", $regID)->first();
```

But its not working, do you know why?

The `dd($registration)` shows:

```
Registration {#342 ▼
  #relations: array:1 [▼
    "invoice" => Invoice {#353 ▼
      #attributes: array:5 [▼
        "id" => 1
        "invoice_number" => 0125
        "registration_id" => 1
        "updated_at" => null
      ]
      #original: array:5 [▶]
    }
  ]
}
```

The "`dd($registration->invoice);`" shows:

```
"Y"
```

The `dd($registration->invoice->invoice_number)` shows "`Trying to get property of non-object`".

Registration model:

```
public function invoice()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Invoice');
    }
```

Invoice model:

```
class Invoice extends Model
{
    public function registration()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Registration');
    }
}
```

Comment: can you add registration model class code in question?

Comment: Are you sure that user will have only one invoice? What the relation between user and invoice/registration.

Comment: Thanks, the user dont have any relation with invoice, only with registrations. In the User model there is " public function registrations(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Registration','user_that_did_registration');
    }".

Comment: can you try `$registration = $user->registrations()->load('invoice')->where("id", $regID)->first();`

Comment: Thanks, like that it appear "Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::load()".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have mismatch with `invoice` column in `registrations` table and `invoice` relation name in model. Just need to change invoice relation name

Registration model:

```
public function invoiceRow()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Invoice');
}
```

This will work, when you have registration id then you can do it like this

```
$registration = Registration::with('invoiceRow')->where("id", $regID)->first();

dd($registration->invoiceRow->invoice_number)
```

Comment: Thanks, but it appear "Trying to get property of non-object
" in "        dd($registration->invoice->invoice_number);
".

Comment: did you check your registration table with `$regID`, does it have invoice assigned ?

Comment: The registrations table has a column "invoice" that if is "Y" means that the usre wants a invoice and "N" means that the user dont wants an invoice. The invoices table has the column "registration_id" to associate the invoice number with a registration_id.

Comment: that field doesn't make any difference, you just check invoice table has `$regID` value ? suppose if you have $regID = 2 then the invoice table should have record with registration_id = 2

Comment: got your problem, you have mismatch with `invoice` column and `invoice` relation name. Just need to change invoice relation name. let me change the answer